# How to flip the object when the mouse is facing the other direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so what I want is when the mouse is on the left the object switches to the left and when the mouse is on the right the weapon faces the right. Got any ideas??

```css
public class WeaponParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float blahblah = 90;
    void Update()
    {
        faceMouse();
    }

    void faceMouse()
    {
        Vector2 dir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position; 
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle -blahblah, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = rotation; 

        
    }
```

Comment: At work so I can't test but try `transform.LookAt(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition))` for starters. Or if you want a hard left / right, check if the `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x` is less or more than `transform.position.x`.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey guys, I figured it out.**

```
{
public float blahblah = 90;
public float offset = 3f;
private SpriteRenderer spriteRender;
public SpriteRenderer brat; 

private void Start()
{
    spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
void Update()
{
    faceMouse();
}

void faceMouse()
{
   // Vector2 dir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position; 
   // float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
   // Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle -blahblah, Vector3.forward);
   // transform.rotation = rotation; 

    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float rot2 = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot2);

    if(rot2 < 69 &&  rot2 > -69)
    {
        Debug.Log("Facing right");
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        brat.flipX = false; 
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Facing left");
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
        brat.flipX = true; 
    }
    
       

    


    
    
}
```

}